# Solutions of Diophantic Equation

Tags: solution-verification, diophantine-equations

> Given the Diophantic Equation
>   $$1188x +63y =26$$
>   Task: Find integer solution(s)

I found that 
$$1188x +63y =26 \Longleftrightarrow 132x+7y = \frac{26}{9}$$
One can easily see that LHS $\in\mathbb Z$ but RHS $\notin \mathbb Z$ for all choices of $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, therefor an integer-solution cannot exist.

Is this a valid proof?

---

**More general:** If I have a Diophantic Equation like 
$$ax+by=c$$
And there is an $d$ with $d\,\vert\, a$ and $d\,\vert\, b$, but $d\,\not\vert\, c$, is it true that an integer solution cannot be found in this case, or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, valid, and yes, impossible.

Comment: Agreed. Another way of giving the same argument: if $1188x+63y=26$, then in particular $1188x+63y\equiv26\pmod9$; this reduces to $0x+0y\equiv8\pmod9$, which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Simpler, it is clear by [casting nines,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) that $\,9\,$ divides the LHS but not the RHS, contradiction.

Generally by [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), $\,ax+by=c\,$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid c.\,$ Indeed, the direction $\,(\Rightarrow)\,$ is clear, and $\,(\Leftarrow)\,$ follows by scaling the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(a,b)\,$ by $\,c/\gcd(a,b).$

Said structurally $\ c\in a\,\Bbb Z + b\,\Bbb Z\, =\, \gcd(a,b)\,\Bbb Z\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid c.\,$ The underlying innate structure becomes clearer after one learns about *ideals*.